# How to replace variable with string in jquery flot graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, flot

I am using Flot line graph which is working alright:

```
data1 = [
    [1430369878000, 1690.25],
    [1430369879000, 1696.3],
    [1430369880000, 1659.65]

];


data2 = [
    [1430369878000, 1682.1],
    [1430369879000, 1680.65],
    [1430369880000, 1685.1]

];
```

However when I replace data1 and data2 with :

```
 dataset = [{
         label: "Team Red",
         data: [
             [1430369878000, 1690.25],
             [1430369879000, 1696.3],
             [1430369880000, 1659.65]
         ],
         color: "#FF0000",
         points: {
             fillColor: "#FF0000",
             show: true
         },
         lines: {
             show: true
         }
     }, {
         label: "Team Blue",
         data: [
             [1430369878000, 1682.1],
             [1430369879000, 1680.65],
             [1430369880000, 1685.1],
             color: "#0062E3",
             points: {
                 fillColor: "#0062E3",
                 show: true
             },
             lines: {
                 show: true
             }
         }
     ];
```

It just wont work, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a closing square bracket for your second `data` value. Try this instead:

```
dataset = [
    {
        label: "Team Red",
        data: [
            [1430369878000, 1690.25],
            [1430369879000, 1696.3],
            [1430369880000, 1659.65]
        ],
        color: "#FF0000",
        points: {
            fillColor: "#FF0000",
            show: true
        },
        lines: {
            show: true
        }
    }, {
        label: "Team Blue",
        data: [
            [1430369878000, 1682.1],
            [1430369879000, 1680.65],
            [1430369880000, 1685.1]
        ],
        color: "#0062E3",
        points: {
            fillColor: "#0062E3",
            show: true
        },
        lines: {
            show: true
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: No worries... been there, done that, kicked myself afterwards ;-)